# Navigation and loading time in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got a project that uses angular technology and the entire html part has been written in one single index.html file. The nav bar contains 4 hyperlinks and each hyperlink contains a video and some content. If the user clicks a hyperlink the entire index.html page loads again (means all 4 videos and content loads and then the respective clicked hyperlink's video plays) Without segregating the pages to 4 seperate page how can we reduce the loading time?

Comment: have you tried attaching the video and the content dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Is there any preload method in angular js that can be used here so that the video gets preloaded before the index.html loads? I am new to angular js.

Comment: try to load html content using ng-if condition , initially load only first video by default.